# bottom navigation change orientation with fragments

Tags: android, fragment, orientation, bottomnavigationview

I'm using bottom navigation view and when I change the orientation portrait to landscape. And current item and fragment change to one, but he was two or another. How to save item's position?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean and what you want to know. As a new member to this site you should read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consider to edit your question to specify your problem more cleary.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something similar to this

```
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        savedInstanceState.putInt("SelectedItemId", bottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId());
    }

    @Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
        int selectedItemId = savedInstanceState.getInt("SelectedItemId");
        bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(selectedItemId);
    }
```